# How to open text files in a text editor?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, editor, vb.net-2010

I recently made a code editor in vb.net for personal use. The only issue I am having is using it as my default text editor. I can open the files from inside the program using an open file dialog and the read all text command but when I double click on a text file it opens my program but the text doesn't appear in the box. I didn't expect it to be that easy but I also didn't expect it to this hard to find an answer. If there is already an open topic that I couldn't find that has the answer on it please leave me a link. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from adding file associations for your app, you will also need to process the commandline to find out what file(s) your app is being fed.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59639-associating-your-program-with-file-types/